# show matrix completion is SDP

Tags: convex-optimization

I am working on showing a matrix completion problem is a SDP. Specifically, we want to show 
\begin{array}
\underset{minimize}_{ X\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}} & \sum_{(i,j) \in \Omega} ( X_{ij} - Z_{ij} )^2 + \lambda \| X \|_{tr}
\end{array}
is a SDP.

I know we can formulate $\|X\|_{tr}$ using its dual hence the above problem could be written as:

\begin{array}
\underset{minimize}_{X\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n},W_1\in\mathbb{S^{m}},W_2\in\mathbb{S^n}}  &\sum_{(i,j) \in \Omega} ( X_{ij} - Z_{ij} )^2 + \lambda(\text{tr}(W_1)+\text{tr}(W_2))\\
\text{subject to} & \begin{pmatrix}
W_1 & \frac{1}{2} X\\
\frac{1}{2}X^{T}  W_2\\
\end{pmatrix}\succeq0 
\end{array}

But I do not see how to show this is a SDP, either in usual form or canonical form.

Thanks.

Comment: In SDP, the objective function is *linear*. You have a quadratic objective function.